# ADF Pipeline Use variable inside another Set Variable

Tags: azure-data-factory

I have two activities inside a for each

1. Set variable 1 - Value is a string. I want to add this string to the content of Set Variable 2

   `@item().MessageType`   (eg :- EVENT, TYPE , STATUS etc. These are the output of a dataflow activity)

2. Set variable 2 :

   @activity('df_dataflow_activity').output.runStatus.output.CacheWaterMarkValue.value[0].EVENT

Here, I want to dynamically change the last part to EVENT,STATUS etc.

```
@activity('df_dataflow_activity').output.runStatus.output.CacheWaterMarkValue.value[0].{get value of Variable 1)
```

I tried but getting unable to parse error.

```
`@activity('df_dataflow_activity').output.runStatus.output.CacheWaterMarkValue.value[0].EVENT`
```

gives me result of 99999 . The last part EVENT/TYPE/STATUS I want it to be dynamic

Answer (score 0):

Set Variable is used to store the value into a variable. You can use that variable in later activities.

You can include the variable which is used in set variable1 in set variable2.

**Set variable1:**

[image]

**Set Variable2:**

`@concat('sample_',variables('var1'))`

[image]

Comment: Using concat function I'm able to generate the dynamic content I want, but I want to execute this ang get the value.  Set Variable 2 I'm getting as @activity('df_dataflow_activity').output.runStatus.output.CacheWaterMarkValue.value[0].EVENT . I would like to execute this and get the result

Comment: Can you please provide a snip of your error?